# Is there a Rails 3 replacement for subclasses_of?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get all derived classes for a specific type. In Rails 2+, you can say:

```
Class.subclasses_of SomeClass
```

This is because activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/extending.rb is gone in Rails 3.

Is there a replacement in Rails 3? Are there alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all the subclasses of SomeClass, then you do:

```
SomeClass.descendants
```

Likewise, if you want to find out the parent classes, use:

```
SomeClass.ancestors
```

This will pass you back an Array for your consumption. Thus allowing you to:

```
SomeClass.descendants.each { |klass| }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always the option to search the ObjectSpace - something like:

```
classes = []
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |klass|
  SomeClass > klass
end
```

Which is a little wonky but useful.  With more context, maybe there's a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question. I never used the subclasses_of method in Rails 2. In Rails 3 I just use `Foo.descendants` which provides an array of classes (and their attributes) that inherit from `Foo`. Very handy.

Comment: subclasses is depreciated in Rails 3. Use descendants instead.